# E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

hello I have a problem with the OnePlus6, this device is detected as having no bluetooth

here is the method that activates bluetooth:

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    boolean fAdapterEnabled = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled();
    try {
        if (!fAdapterEnabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("bgx_dbg", "Exception caught while calling isEnabled.");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Exception caught", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I want to clarify this code works perfectly with another smartphone

here is the mistake I have:

> 2019-01-25 14:16:57.571 28761-28761/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth
>   binder is null 2019-01-25 14:16:57.590 28761-28761/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.clj.blesample, PID: 28761
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null
>   object reference

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code given above this seems to be a bluetooth adapter issue which can happen when you either don't give the application the correct permissions in the manifest shown below or the bluetooth is broken. I have added code below which you should use to take into consideration of faulty bluetooth, also make a utility class which you can call this from.

Note: its the bluetooth adapter null not isEnabled

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Code:

```
public static boolean isBluetoothEnabled() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why this error occurs with a OnePlus and not with a Samsung.

Comment: The one plus device u have could have a hardware issue. Try another one plus or use an emulator that has a bluetooth enabled